# How Java regex match for non-subsequence string?

Tags: java, regex, match

Example:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/abcd.jpg";
String url2 = "http://www.google.com/abcd.jpg_xxx.jpg";
```

I want to match "http://www.google.com/abcd" whatever url or url2.

I write a regex:

```
(http://.*\.com/[^(.jpg)]*).jpg
```

But `[^(.jpg)]*` doesn't like correct. What the regex should be?

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash need to be escaped as well. Use this regex:

```
^(http:\/\/.+?\.com\/[^.]+)\.jpg
```

[**Live Demo**](http://www.rubular.com/r/cxgCHLDNAr)

Comment: Sorry had an unnecessary `$` corrected it now. Please check now or see live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/cxgCHLDNAr

Comment: another question, if I want to match any substring except 'abc', what can I write?

Comment: You can use negative lookahead for that e.g.: `(?!abc).*` Read more about lookaheads here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 0):

Reluctant quantifier `.*?` matches to first ".jpg":

```
(http:\/\/.*\.com\/.*?)\.jpg.*
```